Is there a clean way to template match lvalue or value but not rvalue?
So far the best I've come up with is a wrapper function for every function, like this:
template<class A, class B>
coro<var> operator+(A && a, B && b)
{
    return [] (A a, B b) -> coro<var> {
        var y {a.value() + b.value()};
        co_yield y;
        a.backward(y.grad());
        b.backward(y.grad());
    }(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b));
}

// OR (since I'm not using initial_suspend)

template<class A, class B>
coro<var> operator+(A && _a, B && _b)
{
    A a = std::forward<A>(_a);
    B b = std::forward<B>(_b);
    var y {a.value() + b.value()};
    co_yield y;
    a.backward(y.grad());
    b.backward(y.grad());
}

but the extra bloat is annoying, especially considering there could be a hundred functions like this.
For more context, the goal is to support expressions with temporaries, like a + b + c but to capture the temporaries by value so they don't become dangling in coroutines. However, expressions with lvalue references need to not copy the data since
they are nodes in a DAG potentially with other references.
I'm hoping there's just some clever template-deduction or overload-resolution trick that can do all the magic in one place so each of my coroutine functions becomes slimmer.
It's a shame that c++ coroutines don't offer some customization trait or something that lets you tell the coroutine state to capture rvalue args by value.

There's no way to distinguish temps from references. What I'd do is template <class A, class B> coro<var> operator+(A a, B b) { co_return {a.value() + b.value()}; }. What's wrong with that? Feel free to extend to a MVCE https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de7d7b8879bcdbb4

The problem with that is always copying the arguments. If I do var a,b=...; auto c=a+b; auto d=a*b; the coro's c and d should call .backward() on the same a and b objects. I need to preserve lvalue args for this reason. (btw what is MVCE?)

https://www.google.com/search?q=mvce+stackoverflow I'm really confused how the side effects sometimes matter and sometimes silently operate on temps. Perhaps you need &&-qualified grad() member functions?

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b75838459f8c7c7 should print c = 3.432 c.grad = 1 a.grad = 4.42 b.grad = 2.64 but if you let the corotines copy everything it will "break the chain" of backward()'s and get incorrect results

To directly answer your question, it's because the temps are holding references (or copies) to their "inputs" so the side effects propagate back eventually to lvalues that we care about.

I'm afraid you're making an overly clever design. Perhaps you just need (much) better name instead of coro. Perhaps variable makes more sense? If I squint really hard I might guess you're implementing numerical methods for ODE or something (way out my league there). If this is the case, I'd personally think your clever "hack" is already pretty elegant, really. The code emitted should already be pretty efficient

perfectly-capturing-a-perfect-forwarder-universal-reference-in-a-lambda might interest you: capture by value for rvalues, and by reference_wrapper lvalues.
